# How to set classpath for a config file

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I have a jar file and a config file which is required to execute in the same directory on a unix box. How do I set the classpath to the config file while executing the jar?

i.e something.jar and something.config are in the same directory say dir1.

I navigate to dir1 and run the following command

```
dir1> java -cp something.config -jar something.jar
```

But the jar is not able to find something.config file.

Comment: How is `something.config` accessed in the application?

Answer (score 0):

If both are in same directory then you only need

```
dir1> java -cp . -jar something.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fragment of code in a `Primes.java` class that loads a list of prime numbers from a data file in the same folder.

```
private static final ArrayList<Integer> SomePrimes = new ArrayList<>();
private static final String PrimesFileName = "10000Primes.txt";

static {
    try (InputStream in = Primes.class.getResourceAsStream(PrimesFileName);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
        for (String s; br.ready() && (s = br.readLine()) != null;) {
            // Split into commas.
            String[] ps = s.split(",");
            for (String p : ps) {
                if (p.length() > 0) {
                    SomePrimes.add(Integer.valueOf(p));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Loading pf primes failed.");
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```

Essentially, you need to use `class.getResourceAsStream`.

Answer (score 0):

use can use these methods to set classpath

```
java -cp . -jar Yourjarname.jar// the . represent the current dir.
```

or

```
set classpath=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\lib; //whatever your dir is..
```